# @Input() returns [object Object] Typescript Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

Okay, I can't find the error here. I've used this code before and it worked, but never in the same way.

When I use @Input and try to console.log the result I just get [object Object]. Even when I set its default or try to log the name, it says the name is undefined. Here are the 4 files.

hero-card.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hero-card',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/play/hero-card/hero-card.html'
})
export class HeroCard {
    @Input() hero = {name : 'loading'};
    printHero(){
        console.log(this.hero);
    }
}
```

hero-card.html

```
<div class="hero-card" (click)="printHero()">
<h1>Hero</h1>
<p>{{hero.name}}</p>
</div>
```

play.html

```
<button class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['/home']">Quit</button>
<div *ngIf="loaded">
<hero-card hero="{{hero}}"></hero-card>
</div>
```

play.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroCard } from './hero-card/hero-card.component';
import { Shaman } from "../../lib/heros/shaman/hero.shaman";

@Component({
    selector: 'play',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/play/play.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HeroCard],
    styles: []
})
export class Play {
    hero: any;
    loaded: boolean;

    load(){
        this.hero = new Shaman();
        console.log(this.hero);
        this.loaded = true;
    }

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.loaded = false;
        this.load();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `[object Object]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hero="{{hero}}"` passes the stringified `hero` to the `hero` property which is probably what leads to `[object Object]`.

Use instead `[hero]="hero"` if `hero` is not supposed to be a string.

Comment: If this solves your problem can you please accept the answer using the white checkmark below the up/downvote buttons to indicate your question is answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`{{}}` interpolation is used to just print/show something on HTML page.

Change your 'play.html'

This is how property is binded:

```
<hero-card [hero]="hero"></hero-card>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this answer? This is what my answer already explains.

Comment: Just to explain that what was the mistake and to tell why suggested changes need to be implemented. He should know the difference between interpolation and property binding. If answer is well explained, future mistakes will be reduced.

Comment: I assumed that's what "`hero="{{hero}}"` passes the stringified hero to the hero property" from my answer is doing.